# E-commerce for custom orders/customer image upload

Tags: ecommerce, shopping-cart

We have a client that needs an e-commerce site set up pretty quickly. As I have no experience with e-commerce, I am looking for some guidance. Basically, the two big features we need are:

1. Ability for customer to add info about order (example: the name the
   customer wants to be put on the customizable product they ordered)
2. Ability for customer to upload photo of product to be customized

I hope this makes sense. Right now I am really looking into Shopify, but I can't tell if it does everything we need. I know you can add order notes when checking out, but not sure about image upload (maybe it can be added as an app through the API?).

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course almost every checkout page will have a comments field, this is standard in most shopping carts.  If this is not sufficient, then creating a custom field for each line item is almost always something that needs to customized by a developer.  (Suggestion at end).
2. Where will they upload the photo?  On the product page or in the cart?  This definitely sounds like a custom thing I think.  I don't know any ecommerce platform that does this out of the box.

I don't think shopify will do this.  Look at extensions/plugins/addons that the shopping cart solution provides.  If nothing found, look into nopcommerce.  There's also Magento, which has loads of extensions.

Do you have developers on staff?  If so, use a platform that is built on language they understand.

Let me know if you have any more questions.